# Bundler ignores css file containing @imports

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bundle

I have a really annoying issue where the bundler is not loading the file `all.css` correctly after publishing, resulting in my datepicker not being styled properly.

Here is the datepicker when debugging from Visual Studio:

[image]

And after publishing the application:

[image]

Where `all.css` simply contains

```
@import "base.css";
@import "theme.css";
@import "jquery-ui.css";
```

And `bundleconfig.cs` contains:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
    .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
    .Include("~/Content/mystyles.css")
    .Include("~/Content/themes/base/all.css"));
```

I noticed that the issue is resolved if I manually add

```
.Include("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css)
```

But this does not explain why this is happening in the first place.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Because, as you say, the Bundler doesn't do @imports. You could write out the @ imports to be a working relative path and the browser would actually import it,

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure what you mean by "write out the @ imports to be a working relative path", would that just involve replacing the file name with the `~/` path? Also do you know why it does work when debugging via VS?

Comment: Because when debugging the stylebundle actually sends along the individual files, instead of the bundled content. With a relative path I mean a path relative to the webroot probably, look at the generated html, it'll look somethign like `/scriptbundle.axd?skjfskdfkshdfk` or `/subsite/scriptbundle.axd?skdfhiksdhfjk`. The imports is attempted relative to the root stylesheet.

Comment: @jessehouwing The css link in generated html is `/Content/css?v=JL20DhPcfkRM5-RvqcJt-_8k8vSh1t5Vze7G6LffyqI1`, but when debugging it just looks normal, e.g. `/Content/Themes/base/all.css`